# How to remove a block device from lsblk list on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, hard-disk, disk, block-device, delete

Here is my `lsblk -a` list:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0    0   10G  0 disk
├─sda1        8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2        8:2    0    9G  0 part
  ├─cl-root 253:0    0    8G  0 lvm  /
  └─cl-swap 253:1    0    1G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdb           8:32   0   16G  0 disk
sr0          11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
drbd0       147:0    0    2G  0 disk
```

I want to remove `drbd0`. How to do?

Comment: Have you try to stop drdb daemon?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Yes. After I ran `systemctl stop drbd` and check `lsblk -a` again, `drbd0` also exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(On a previous question) I suggested that you want to remove the DRBD device, however running `rm` on nodes in `/dev/` does not really achieve this.  E.g. you should see that the kernel view of block devices in `/sys/class/block` is not affected by such changes.

Removing the device node will hide it from lsblk, but it would not cause any claimed resources to be released!  This seems like a bad idea.

Rebooting should remove any weird DRBD devices that you are not using any more.  (E.g. that were removed from drbd config, but still exist for whatever strange reason).

"module load/unload" would be a way to avoid a reboot, if that's what you wanted.  `modprobe -r drbd` to unload.  It would require that you have no other DRBD devices in use.

---

If you believed the drbd daemon was messing around with creating or renaming devices in `/dev` at the same time as `udev` / `devtmpfs` is running, and genuinely had a bug which left behind a stale device node (and some stale cache in `lsblk`), then you'd better do a full reboot to clear up the mess.  Because that would be some really broken software, nothing should be doing that anymore.

Comment: deleting anything in dev falls into the "don't unless you know better" category.  In many years of linux use, I've never known better.

Comment: @DanFarrell I guess you've never typo'ed the destination of a `dd` command then :-P.

Comment: mistakes notwithstanding of course.

Answer (score 2):

As you have stopped `drdb` you may want to check [the thread](http://lists.linbit.com/pipermail/drbd-user/2009-March/011727.html) and follow the recommendation and just remove the device file in `/dev`. Here is extract from the mentioned page:

> > and we also have the drbd device in /dev/ directory, we want to delete
> >     de drbd1 from /dev.
> >
> > `brw-rw---- 1 root disk 147, 0 2009-03-18 15:34 /dev/drbd0`
> >
> > `brw-rw---- 1 root disk 147, 1 2009-03-18 15:34 /dev/drbd1`
> >
> > `brw-rw---- 1 root disk 147, 2 2009-03-18 15:34 /dev/drbd2`
> >
> > `brw-rw---- 1 root disk 147, 3 2009-03-18 15:41 /dev/drbd3`
> >
> > `brw-rw---- 1 root disk 147, 4 2009-03-18 15:41 /dev/drbd4`
>
> you can of course delete the device nodes, if it makes you happy. only
>   it won't magically re-appear in case you want to use it again, (unless
>   you do a reboot or module unload/load). so you would need to mknod it
>   again, if you need it again.

Answer (score 2):

`lsblk` has a `-e` option to exclude devices by major device numbers.

The drbd devices in your `lsblk` output above have a major number of 147, so this will exclude them from the list:

```
lsblk -a -e 147
```

This will not remove any drbd device nodes from your system or interact in any way with the DRBD service, it will just exclude the drbd devices from `lsblk`'s output.